# Sync MongoDB Replica set with Remote Replica Set

Tags: replication, mongodb, migration, aws, google-cloud-platform

I'm wondering if it is possible (within reason) to sync a new MongoDB Replica Set(RS) with an RS currently in production.

**The Problem**

We have a site running on AWS that has its own MongoDB Replica Set and we're working on migrating that site to Google Cloud. We want to start a separate RS on Google Compute that will catch up with the AWS RS and stay up to date during our QA lifecycle until we're ready to cut DNS over to Google.

We originally tried adding the replicas on Google as secondaries to the AWS RS to keep them in sync. Our plan was to then take the AWS RS offline and let the Google RS reassign a Primary and continue as the only RS after the site was completely migrated.

This caused some issues when one of the Google replicas got elected as a master and created some syncing issues with our current live site.

**The Solution??**

I've been debating if it's possible to rsync from the AWS Primary to the GCloud Primary. Is this doable with Mongo? Will the GCloud primary then properly replicate to its slaves?

Or...

Is there a better solution that anyone knows of for this problem?

**UPDATE**

After trying to add Google nodes to server we're not seeing the node sync:

```
INFRA-GENERAL-00:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
"set" : "INFRA-GENERAL-00",
"date" : ISODate("2016-08-03T00:22:37.275Z"),
"myState" : 2,
"term" : NumberLong(2),
"heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "****:27017",
        "health" : 0,
        "state" : 8,
        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
        "uptime" : 0,
        "optime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-08-03T00:22:35.205Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "exception: field not found, expected type 16",
        "configVersion" : -1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "****:27017",
        "health" : 0,
        "state" : 8,
        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
        "uptime" : 0,
        "optime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-08-03T00:22:34.728Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "exception: field not found, expected type 16",
        "configVersion" : -1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "****:27017",
        "health" : 0,
        "state" : 8,
        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
        "uptime" : 0,
        "optime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-08-03T00:22:35.248Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "exception: field not found, expected type 16",
        "configVersion" : -1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "name" : "****:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 338,
        "optime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1470169610, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(2)
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-08-02T20:26:50Z"),
        "configVersion" : 175485,
        "self" : true
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}











INFRA-GENERAL-00:SECONDARY> rs.config()
2016-08-03T00:23:49.051+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Could not     retrieve replica set config: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command {     replSetGetConfig: 1.0 }",
"code" : 13
} :
rs.conf@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1091:11
@(shell):1:1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems we were unable to add Mongo 3.2 servers to Mongo 2.4 cluster, so we've decided to downgrade our cluster we're migrating to and look into upgrading later. After downgrading to Mongo 2.4 on our Google cluster, replication is working well.

A helpful strategy when migrating to a new system is to make sure none of the servers in the new cluster can vote. This helps you avoid the replica set going through phases where there are an even number of members, which can break things. More on non-voting replicas here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-a-non-voting-replica-set-member/

Also, as @Adam C mentioned, it is important to set the new members to priority 0, this will keep them from being elected as primary. (This did not seem to keep them from participating in election, so we used the votes config)

Answer (score 3):

You can follow your original strategy with a minor tweak: add Google Compute (GC) nodes into the current replica set and keep them in sync until ready to cut over. The only thing you need to change is to set those new GC nodes to have [priority 0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-priority-0-member/). They will be full members of the set, they just [cannot be elected primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-secondary-only-replica-set-member/) (or trigger elections).

Once you are ready to switch over to the Google nodes, you need only reset the priority to 1 (or whatever your normal values are), and then [step down](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.stepDown/) or remove the AWS nodes from the set. You can guarantee that a GC node is elected primary by giving them a higher priority than the AWS nodes before issuing the step down.

Comment: Do you know if replication works from mongo ~2.4 to ~3.2?

Comment: This is one of those questions: will it work? probably, should you rely on it? no - it's not supported to have replication between major versions. Generally I would not recommend upgrading and migrating at the same time either, it would be safer to upgrade first then migrate or vice versa

Comment: For some reason we're unable to attach the remote mongo instance on Google to the AWS Cluster. Posted status in original post.

Comment: I'm afraid all that tells me is that you can't connect to any of the other nodes that you have listed from the node you ran the command on. Can you telnet to those hosts or connect with the mongo shell to them on 27017? I suspect you cannot. You must have routing/connectivity between the various nodes for this to work (public IPs with whitelisting would be the most obvious approach). Your question suggested you had this working since a node in GC was elected primary, but your status suggests it is not working now

Comment: It looks like we're unable to replicate from 2.4 to 3.2. We ran a 2.4 version on Google and it started replicating just fine.